# src/index.ts:12:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './schema.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, graphql

hi I want to import a graphql file. For this i have installed babel-plugin-import-graphql package.but for some reason i am getting error

```
\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:750
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:12:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './schema.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations.

12 import typeDefs from "./schema.graphql";
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**how do i do the import**

```
import typeDefs from "./schema.graphql";
```

**graphql.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.graphql" {
  import { DocumentNode } from "graphql";

  const value: DocumentNode;
  export = value;
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["import-graphql"]
}
```

full code can be viewed [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-frog-fds87?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: ... and you're following tutorial ... ? who told you it should be done that way? graphql schema != TS type defs ... probably you're looking for TS types generator from graphql schema, use google/search

Comment: and who said that this should not be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file from <strike>`src/@types/graphql.d.ts`</strike> to `src/@types/index.d.ts`, leave the contents the same, and restart the TS server (or just reload the IDE).